# How to get/find the firmware version of device/controller using node js in azure?

Tags: node.js, azure-iot-hub

How to get/find the firmware version of device/controller using node js in azure?

> The device is actually added in IoT Hub on Azure. I'm using node.js
>   framework to fetch the firmware version.

Below I have added my device. Device works as expected. I just want/fetch firmware version.
[Please click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuFzL.png)

Comment: needs more details - you mean that you added a firmware version property in your device twin and want to retrieve that property from the twin?

Comment: Thanks pierreca. By using device twin I have retrieve the current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

```
//*N++ update table
var macId = GetDeviceId();
updateFirmwareVersion(macId);


//*N+start update firmware version
function updateFirmwareVersion(deviceId){
    registry.getTwin(deviceId, function(err, twin){
        if (err) {
          console.log('Could not query twins: ' + err.constructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
        } else {
          console.log((JSON.stringify(twin.properties.reported.AzureFwVersion)) + "\n");
          var azureFwVersion = twin.properties.reported.AzureFwVersion;
          var s = azureFwVersion.lastIndexOf(".");

          var res = azureFwVersion.substring(s+1, azureFwVersion.length);
          var firmwareV = Number(res).toString(16).toUpperCase() + '00';

             //SQL starts
            new sql.Request()
                    .query("UPDATE MY_Table SET firmware = '" + firmwareV + "'").then(function (recordset) {
               }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('update table for firmware' + err);
            });

        }
    });
}
//*N+end update firmware version
```

Please refer below link for detail
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-firmware-update#trigger-a-remote-firmware-update-on-the-device-using-a-direct-method